# FTP from batch file

Tags: windows, ftp, scripting, batch-file

I'm trying to use a batch file to download a package off my FTP server.

```
echo username >ftp.txt
echo >>ftp.txt
echo cd directory  >>ftp.txt
echo get filename >>ftp.txt

ftp -s:ftp.txt server.com
```

The server is set to allow anonymous logins on username but when I run the script I get an error: 331 Password required for username

If there is any other useful information let me know.

-Alex

Comment: What happens when you connect in interactive mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trailing space where i was inserting into the textfile was screwing up the login

I removed the spaces and it's letting me in.

Thanks for the suggestions

-Alex

Answer (score 1):

Try "anonymous" as the login and an email address as the password.  This is a *very* old standard for anonymous FTP.

Comment: Only a specific username is allowed anonymous access and it does not require a password

Comment: Then you should be able to provide a script by recreating _exactly_ what is typed when you login via an interactive session.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to begin your ftp.txt with

`open server.com`

You could use

`ftp -s:ftp.txt`

---

EDIT

So I would try, in your ftp.txt

```
open server.com
username

ftp_commands
bye
```

Note the blank line after the username.

Comment: Same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

What's the FTP server?  Some say "anonymous" log in but still require *something* to be entered as a password (usually it's looking for an e-mail address) before it will accept the log in.  What's the behavior when you connect to the account using a regular FTP client with a blank password?

Comment: When I connect manually I do "FTP server.com" it prompts for user: "username" it says I'm allowed to do anonymous login and asks for a password (suggesting email): "I hit enter" and I'm in